# I'm trying to make a Java File Server

Tags: java, html, file, http, server

**Basically what I'm trying to do is have a some server code running on any machine and being able to access and download all of the files and folders on that machine. I've attached my code at the bottom but here's what I have, what I know, and where I'm stuck:**

EDIT:
*I've been told my question is too abstract and not clear. I've figured out how to get my files in list. Now I need to list them inside the 'payLoad' string.*

- I know I've hard coded the file browser. It just helped me get started visually. It says 'some files' and 'some folders' because that is where I want them to go.
- I've got the files loaded into an Array because they're dynamic. Now I'm to get the array list to load into the HTML table.
- I know there are http and URL things I have to do, like GET and POST to actually download the files but I still need help to get started

  ```
  import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.awt.Desktop;
  import java.net.URI;

  class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      File folder = new File("/Users/DeAndre");
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
      int c = 0;
      // Listen for a connection from a client
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
      if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
          Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://localhost:1234"));
      else

          System.out.println("Please direct your browser to http://localhost:1234.");
          while(true) {
              Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
              System.out.println("Got a connection!");
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
              String dateString = (new Date()).toGMTString();
              while(c<listOfFiles.length) {
                  String payload = "\t\t<table>\n" +
                          "\t\t<tr><td align=right>Current directory:</td><td>/some/path/</td></tr>\n" +
                          "\t\t<tr><td>\n" +
                          "\t\t<b>Folders:</b><br>\n" +
                          "\t\t<select id=\"folderList\" size=\"15\" style=\"width: 280px\" onchange=\"javascript:location.href=this.value;\">\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"index.html?cd=..\">..</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"index.html?cd=somefolder\">somefolder</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"index.html?cd=anotherfolder\">anotherfolder</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"index.html?cd=yetanotherone\">yetanotherfolder</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t</select>\n" +
                          "\t\t</td><td>\n" +
                          "\t\t<b>Files:</b><br>\n" +
                          "\t\t<select id=\"fileList\" size=\"15\" style=\"width: 280px\">\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"somefile.txt\">somefile.txt</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"somefile.txt\">" + listOfFiles[20].getName() + "</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t\t<option value=\"anotherfile.jpeg\">anotherfile.jpeg</option>\n" +
                          "\t\t</select>\n" +
                          "\t\t</td></tr></table>" + listOfFiles[1];
                  c++;

              for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                      System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                      System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                  }
              }


              // Receive the request from the client
              String inputLine;
              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println("The client said: " + inputLine);
                  if (inputLine.length() < 2)
                      break;
              }

              //File Browser

              // Send HTTP headers
              System.out.println("Sending a response...");
              out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
              out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
              out.print("Content-Length: " + Integer.toString(payload.length()) + "\r\n");
              out.print("Date: " + dateString + "\r\n");
              out.print("Last-Modified: " + dateString + "\r\n");
              out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
              out.print("\r\n");

              // Send the payload
              out.println(payload);
              System.out.println("Done.");
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Side note. For some reason, people forget the definition of the word help and just turn very rude. Please. I know there's a lot I don't know, that's why I want to learn. I'm stuck. The right direction would be helpful.

Comment: To get a specific answer, you need to ask a specific question. If you want a code review, there is another site for that.  This forum is for definitive answers on clear programming questions, which are not opinion based. This forum doesn't attempt to be all things to all people.

Comment: @PeterLawrey StackOverflow [is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

Comment: @cricket_007 good point.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is a specific question in there. "Basically what I'm trying to do is have a some server code running on any machine and being able to access and download all of the files and folders on that machine" There is my goal. My question **How do I get the stored string names in the  File ArrayList into a HTML list**

Comment: You have a for loop that prints the filenames.  Change it to append to a string instead.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That still doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to learn here is a tip. Don't implement the complete logic into a single method. It is better to split one large method into several methods like

```
private void sendHttpHeaders(PrintWriter out, String payload, String dateString) {
    System.out.println("Sending a response...");
    out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    out.print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
    out.print("Content-Length: " + Integer.toString(payload.length()) + "\r\n");
    out.print("Date: " + dateString + "\r\n");
    out.print("Last-Modified: " + dateString + "\r\n");
    out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
    out.print("\r\n");
}
```

This makes code more readable. Hint: inline comments are a good indication for creating a new method.

Greetings,
Martin

Comment: Thanks but that still leaves me confused about my main question. This just makes my code more readable. Is that just a coders preference? Does this make it faster?

Comment: No, it doesn't make it faster, but it is more readable and therefore more interesting for others to read.